# Trying to move a circle using graphics library Ocaml

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I am new to ocaml and trying to move a circle using Graphics library of Ocaml.
This is what I did but it is not working. It should continue for infinite time because of "while true" but it is not working and I am not able to give an Input.

```
#load "graphics.cma";;
#load "unix.cma";;

Graphics.open_graph " 800x250";;
Graphics.remember_mode true;;
Graphics.set_color 100;;
Graphics.foreground;;

let player = [|40;80;10|];;

Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2);;

let rec check button = 
    if button = 'w'
    then
    player.(0) <- player.(0) + 50;
    Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2);

while true do
    let s = Graphics.wait_next_event [Graphics.Button_down; Graphics.Key_pressed]
    and bo=Graphics.key_pressed ()
    in if not bo then check s.Graphics.key;
    done;;
```

Comment: "It is not working" is quite a general description of the problem. It might help if you showed some kind of output. This looks like code to be run in the toplevel. So, can you show what the toplevel says after you type each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the cause of problems:

```
 Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2);
                                                 ^^^^^^^
                       here should be a double semicolon
```

Without a second semicolon, the while expression was considered as
a part of `check` function, the proper indentation clarifies this:

```
let rec check button = 
  if button = 'w'
  then
    player.(0) <- player.(0) + 50;
  Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2);

  while true do
    let s = Graphics.wait_next_event [Graphics.Button_down; Graphics.Key_pressed]
    and bo=Graphics.key_pressed ()
    in if not bo then check s.Graphics.key;
  done
```

So, you just defined a function check, and never called it, that's why nothing was happening.

Also, OCaml is a programming language, so it is better to try to write OCaml programs, not scripts. Put the following in a `graph.ml` file,

```
let player = [|40;80;10|]

let init () = 
  Graphics.open_graph " 800x250";
  Graphics.remember_mode true;
  Graphics.set_color 100;
  Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2)

let rec check button = 
  if button = 'w'
  then
    player.(0) <- player.(0) + 50;
  Graphics.fill_circle player.(0) player.(1) player.(2)

let run () = 
  while true do
    let s = Graphics.wait_next_event [
        Graphics.Button_down;
        Graphics.Key_pressed
      ] in
    let bo = Graphics.key_pressed () in
    if not bo then check s.Graphics.key;
  done


let () =
  init ();
  run ()
```

Compile and run it with the following command

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg graphics graph.native --
```

Comment: can you please explain how can i remove the previous circle whenever I move forward and create a new circle. And thanks for the previous answer.